# Simple barplot: ggplot2 functions that is equivalent to barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This may be a dumb question, but I've been searching for a little while. Suppose this is my data and the plots I want to make.

```
counts <- as.matrix(data.frame(A = c(3,5), B = c(8,10), C = c(5,6)))
barplot(counts[1,])
barplot(counts, beside = TRUE)
```

[image]
[image]
How can I do the same thing in ggplot2? Here's my failed attempt.

```
c2 <- data.frame(labels = c('A','B', 'C'), v1 = c(3,8,5), v2 = c(5,10,6))
qplot(x=labels, y=v1, data=c2, geom = "bar", stat='identity', color='red')
```

The data here is different from most tutorials for ggplot2's bar plot. It is much simpler. Basically, I have three labels: A, B, C and according numbers and I just want to plot them in the bar shape.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this want you want? `ggplot(c2, aes(x=labels, y=v1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Comment: Yep, thank you ~ Here's how to do side-by-side, if anyone is curious: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3842/how-to-create-a-barplot-diagram-where-bars-are-side-by-side-in-r

Answer (score 1):

You can melt the data and use variable name to fill the bar. To put them side by side, use `position="dodge"`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

c <- melt(c2, id="labels")
ggplot(c, aes(x=labels, y=value, fill=variable)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]